# Set up FTP for use with WordPress on CentOS

Tags: wordpress, ftp, vsftpd

I have recently set up WordPress on my VPS, and everything is working, except for FTP. I have vsftpd already installed, but have no idea how to configure a user and any general settings to work with WordPress. I currently cannot connect to the VPS by FTP, with a "failure to connect" error brought up. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Surely you can find the information you need by searching Google. Here are a few resources to get you started:

1. http://howto.gumph.org/content/setup-virtual-users-and-directories-in-vsftpd/
2. http://centoshelp.org/servers/installing-configuring-vsftpd/
3. http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/rackspace-cloud-essentials-5-centos-configuring-a-user-in-vsftpd